# How to delete 2D Array after its modified by a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

So, I've made a function that looks like this:

```
const char **myFunction(char *string)
{   
    char *bufCopy = new char[strlen(string)];
    strcpy(bufCopy,string);
    char *tmp = func1(bufCopy);

    const char **RetVector = new const char* [6];
    RetVector[0] = tmp;

    return RetVector;
}
```

func1 (that is strtok) modified the first argument, so when I delete[] it gives me heap corruption. What could I do?

Comment: `bufCopy` should be allocated `strlen(string) + 1;` . Extra character for null termination. Use std::vector<std::string>

Comment: Maybe the heap corruption is from the buffer overflow... your allocated string is one char short since strlen() doesn't account for the terminating '\0'.

Comment: Thank you, bufCopy is declares as following: char bufCopy[x] = {0};

Answer (score 1):

You *must* always keep track of the original allocation of your `bufCopy`, only that one can be `delete`d. `tmp` probably only points to part of it (inside the buffer somewhere), so you can't `delete` it.

Comment: I debugged the application and the value I allocate, return and - try- to delete has the same address at the start and at the end (when returning) of the function